# Is $W$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: complex-numbers, convex-analysis

Let 
$$
W=\{(1,2\Re e(x\overline{y});\;(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2\;\;\hbox{and}\;|x|^2+|y|^2=1\}
$$

> Is $W$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We consider the polar coordinates of the complex numbers. So let be $x=r_xe^{t_xi}$ and $y=r_ye^{t_yi}$ where $r_x,r_y\geq 0$ and $t_x,t_y\in[0,2\pi)$. The condition $|x|^2+|y|^2=1$ becomes $r_x^2+r_y^2=1$. Therefore we are free to choose the angle $t_x$ and $t_y$.

Now $$
\Re(x\bar y)=\Re\left(r_xr_ye^{(t_x+t_y)i}\right)=r_xr_y\cos(t_x+t_y).
$$
Since we can freely choose $t_x$ and $t_y$ we can get all values in $[-r_xr_y,r_xr_y]$.

We deduce that $W=\{1\}\times[-R,R]$, where $R$ is the maximal value of $2r_xr_y$ restricted to $r_x^2+r_y^2=1$.

Hence $W$ is convex.